# MVVM pattern. Am I understand this correctly?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm pretty familiar w Windows Forms, but am just getting started in WPF and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the MVVM pattern.

Is the DRY principle not goal in the WPF mindset? Because this pattern has me basically replicating my entire model into ViewModels so I can raise `INotifyPropertyChanged` in my setters.

```
//from ModelView
public string FirstName
{
    get 
    { 
        return employee.FirstName; 
    }
    set
    {
        if(employee.FirstName != value)
        {
                employee.FirstName = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }
}
```

I get that the idea is to decouple the domain object from the view, but maybe I'm missing some other mental step in the process.  Does validation get moved into the viewmodel? That seems to be a bad idea because no matter the front end the data would still need the same restrictions. Which brings us to needing ICommands and delegates to get that stuff exposed.

What am I missing? Obviously there is some aspect of this pattern that I am not seeing.

Comment: You should have this inside your Model I assume?

Comment: While the other question is tagged Silverlight instead of WPF, it's the same issue, which applies to WPF as well as Silverlight.

Comment: If you want to bind two ways against your models, then they should implement INPC.  Whether you do it directly, or wrap them with a one-off custom wrapper, or create a wrapper that can be used with any instance of any type.  I've done all three.  #1 is usually easiest.  #3 I'll probably nuget some day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question here is whether to write a view model class for each model class or simply expose the model object through a property of a view model.

I think it depends on the project: How different are the view models from the models, how big is the project, is the domain used for other applications, etc.

You should read [the article 'MVVM: To Wrap or Not to Wrap? '](http://blog.alner.net/archive/2010/02/09/mvvm-to-wrap-or-not-to-wrap.aspx) for more information.

Comment: That is a very succinct and accurate way of wording my question.  Thank you for understanding my rambling.  I'll read the the link and mark as the answer if that ends up being what I'm looking for.

Comment: I think the answer is "it depends" for smaller projects I like to directly use the model classes, for bigger projects it makes sense to wrap them... but this may be very time consuming (think of observable compositions, etc.)

Comment: The article ended up being pretty much what I was looking for.  Thanks for the pointer.  Marked as answered.